# detecting text change in uitextfied?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, user-interface, uitextfield

I would like to detect a change in uitextfield and when ever there is a change in uitextfield then I would like to call a method so could anyone provide me some code showing how to do that.

thanks, 
TC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UITextField calls this method on its delegate when a user has entered new text:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Here's a [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) to all the methods that a UITextField can call on its delegate.

You can return NO from the method if you don't want to allow the change.  You can set the delegate of you UITextControl like this:

```
myTextField.delegate = myObjThatIsTheDelegateForThisTextField;
```

It may already be setup in your xib file, though.

**EDIT**

To connect up your UITextField if you're using InterfaceBuilder, right-click on the UITextField in the window and drag a line to the cube that represents your view controller (probably the third cube in the MyView.xib?)  Then select delegate from the popup that appears.

Comment: that isn't working for some reason here is the code i put in the viewcontroller of the view where the uitextfield is: - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)downloadSourceField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
 NSLog(@"the text is going to change");

}

Comment: It's important that your textfield's delegate is set.  Have you tried assigning the delegate to your viewcontroller?

Comment: what do I replace myObjThatIsTheDelegateForThisTextField with?